# Использование имени вторичного ключа FK

Tags: база-данных

Имена вторичных ключей во всех таблицах MySQL имеют одинковый формат, наподобии:

```
FK_7t1xj4qgs0fmhdqggh2fkocqo
```

Да, при создании имени ключа нет строгих требований, но все таки хотелось бы понимать как я могу создать имя Вторичного Ключа с таким же форматом.

- Используются цифры и буквы
- кол-во символов после FK_ - 25

Comment: А зачем вам это знать? Скорее всего используется какая-то хеш-функция, которая преобразует имя вида FK_SrcTableName.ColumnName_TagetTableName.ColumnName в кракозябру выше.

Comment: в чем сложность?) пишешь fk-и пдаешь *бальнико на клавиатуру)

Comment: @iluxa1810 Если можно приведи плз. конкретный пример.

Comment: @АйзекАзимов - так себе вариант)

Comment: byte[] bytesOfMessage = "yourString".getBytes("UTF-8");

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);

BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1,thedigest);
String hashtext = bigInt.toString(36);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём  того, что имена внешних ключей в MySQL по умолчанию другие (для InnoDB `имя-таблицы_ibfk_номер-ключа`). Значит ваши имена сгенерированы не mysql, а кем-то ещё. И вам надо бы узнать, кто создал эти ключи. Например, такие ключи могут генерировать средства создания миграций, какие-нибудь ORM.

Если понять откуда взялись эти ключи невозможно, то можно просто сделать похожие. Проанализируйте эти имена. В вашем примере в качестве суффикса, кажется, используется строка из символов алфавита `[0-9a-z]` это похоже на base36. Значение, которое должно стать префиксом, можно взять из самых разных мест. Например можно взять `md5` от имени таблицы и номера ключа (я на php, но думаю, всё понятно):

```
<?php

$tableName = 'foobar';
$keyNum = 0;
$fkName = 'FK_' .  base_convert(md5($tableName . $keyNum), 16, 36);
echo $fkName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, воспользоваться `uuid()`, заменить тире на пусто и взять 25 символов с любой из сторон.

А так, по факту, возможно, используется какая-то хеш-функция, которой на входе подается длинное сгенерированное имя и она возвращает такую кракозябру.

Comment: uuid это 16 байт. не надо резать его как строку.) в base32 если отрезать = будет 24 символа, а в base36 будет какраз 25